# Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing in mysql (via php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, bar the possible typo should select 3 columns, the 1st being a rank, opposition and a percentage of losses.

```
      SELECT COUNT(B.F_FACTOR) AS RANK, A.F_OPPOSITION, A.F_FACTOR
      FROM
          (
          SELECT
          F_OPPOSITION, 
          IF(SUM(F_RESULT='L',=1,1,0) AS F_NUM,
          IF(SUM(F_RESULT IN ('W','D','L'),=1,1,0) AS F_DENOM,
          ROUND(SUM(F_NUM/F_DENOM),2) AS F_FACTOR
          FROM $table
          GROUP BY F_OPPOSITION 
          ) A,
          (
           SELECT
           F_OPPOSITION, 
           IF(SUM(F_RESULT='L',=1,=1,=0) AS F_NUM,
           IF(SUM(F_RESULT IN ('W','D','L'),=1,=1,=0) AS F_DENOM,
           ROUND(SUM(F_NUM/F_DENOM),2) AS F_FACTOR
           FROM $table
           GROUP BY F_OPPOSITION 
           ) B
     WHERE A.F_FACTOR <= B.F_FACTOR 
           OR (A.F_FACTOR=B.F_FACTOR AND A.F_OPPOSITION=B.F_OPPOSITION)
     GROUP BY A.F_OPPOSITION, F_FACTOR
     ORDER BY A.F_RANK ASC, A.F_FACTOR DESC, A.F_OPPOSITION DESC;
```

it is possible that i run this as a cron job to update a table nightly and then do a basic select x,y,z from that table to display this to screen with php, which i will probably do.

But in terms of learning more from a sql standpoint is their a quicker/easier, both in typing and processing, to achieve the same output.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added cron job to update table created nightly, processing time is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating results in database is (almost) always faster than achieving same from the server side language, PHP in this example. So just run a crontab.

Comment: yes i agree and that is the approach i will take, but this wasn't the answer to the question i wanted, is there a quicker way to right the above statement to get the same output?